# Is this SQL query/join possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am learning SQL and I am looking at SQL joins at the moment.
Playing around with different joins in MySQL and I was wondering if this would be possible, to have it all in 1 column.

DB has 3 tables:

- shops
- prices
- products

Products looks like:

- product_id
- product_name

Shops looks like:

- shop_id
- shop_name

Prices look like:

- price_id
- price_amount
- product_id
- shop_id

So the big question is: is it possible to combine it to have it output like:
product_id,product_name,price_shop1,price_shop2,price_shop3

I got so far that my output is like
product_id,price_amount,shop_id,shop_name, but on 3 different rows.

Can it be done? What kind of join am I looking for if it is possible?

I do not see where I could be using this, just trying to learn.

Thanks.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be help..

Comment: Do you want it all in 1 column or 1 row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, we are talking about making a request with a dynamic number of columns, because you don't know beforehand how many shops with that product are there. This is not supported.

But you can have a single column with all the prices concatenated and comma-separated (or any other symbol you choose).

For example:

```
SELECT
    a.product_id,
    a.product_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.price_amount SEPARATOR ';') prices
FROM
    products a INNER JOIN prices b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
GROUP BY a.product_id
```

This should yield you a list of the products and a list of all their available prices, though in the form of a string that you will have to parse.

If you also wish to include the shops those products are in, I advise you not to do that. Since some parsing is needed either way, just get the full list, which will include product duplicates but you can sort by `product_id` to deal with that easily.